# Copying folders from one repository to another

Tags: svn

I have the following SVN structure:

iPhone -> Project A -> trunk, branch, tags

iPhone -> Project B -> trunk, branch, tags

iPhone -> Project C -> trunk, branch, tags

iPhone is a repository, the other levels are just folders within the repository.

I wish to change this structure so that each project is within its own repository. How do I do this whilst maintaining the version history? Is it possible to dump on a specific folder within a repository and then load that folder back in to a fresh repository?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html) as described in [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5) example.

A quick version that does it all is this

```
$ svnadmin create newrepos
$ svnadmin dump myrepos | svnadmin load newrepos
```

All these commands requires access to the svn server. Without it it's not possible (or, it is but don't go there)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had some issues with svn dump since at one point I had deleted and re-added a couple of folders so it kept complaining about files/folders already existing. I tried to edit the dump file but that didn't work out so just did an export and import but kept the old respositoy for its version history.